# MySQl call in PHP (stored procedure with JSON input)

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Hi everybody (my first question here - havent found any solutions here or by google)

How to make this MySQl call in PHP work (stored procedure with JSON input)?

```
call super_search_cvr('{"keyword": 8, "postcode": 2765, "company_name": "", "max_distance": 300, "limit": 28}');
```

input is defined like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `super_search_cvr_json`(query JSON)
BEGIN
    declare i_keyword int default 99;
    declare i_postcode int(4) default 0;
    declare i_company_name varchar(45) default '';
    declare i_max_distance int default 100;
    declare i_limit int default 40;
```

in PDO or mysqli (i currently use mysqli) - presume i need to use PDO.

Comment: What do you mean by "work"?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was really hoping to get some hits/guide to call a stored procedure with json. As trying different things isnt really best practice - and what is stackedoverflow of if this kind of question is wrong?